# Get session values

Tags: http, ruby-on-rails-4, session, go

My rails app uses session for storing a user credentials for authorization. Trying to sign in and do some actions (that require a user session) in Go code. Should I retrieve a user session when signing in and pass to the next request? How can I handle that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go's standard library does not provide an HTTP session manager. So you have to write one yourself, or use one written by others.

Some examples:

- https://github.com/icza/session - includes Google App Engine support (disclosure: I'm the author)
- https://github.com/gorilla/sessions (part of the [Gorilla web toolkit](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/))

Usually HTTP sessions are managed via cookies between server and client, and as such, the session (session id) can be acquired directly from the request ([`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request)) e.g. with [`Request.Cookie()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Cookie).

That being said it is not necessary to "pass" the session through the "request chain", every handler can access it just by having the `http.Request`.

For example using [`github.com/icza/session`](https://godoc.org/github.com/icza/session) it can be done like this:

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sess := session.Get(r)
    if sess == nil {
        // No session (yet)
    } else {
        // We have a session, use it
    }
}
```

Using [Gorilla sessions](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions), it's similar:

```
var store = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("something-very-secret"))

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := store.Get(r, "session-name")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    // Use session
}
```

Comment: Hi @icza, Can I use this to save a struct instance?

Comment: @gbenroscience You may save any Go value, including structs. But know that each saved value is a copy. So if you put a struct value in it, modifying the original will have no effect on the saved value (which has its pros and cons).

Comment: thanks for responding. I kind of assumed it would work the way you described anyway; thanks again